# Django+Haystack+Whoosh: how to deal with language inflection

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

Many languages in Europe are inflectional. This means that one word can be written in multiple forms in text. For example, word 'computer' in polish "komputer" has multiple forms: "komputera", "komputerowi", "komputerem", "komputery" , etc..

**How should I use django+haystack+whoosh properly to deal with language inflection?**

Whenever I search for any form of "komputer", "komputera", "komputerowi" I mean this same thing ->"komputer".

In NLP there is a basic approach based either on stemming words (cutting suffixes) either on converting a form to the base form ("komputerowi" => "komputer"). There are some libraries that can help with that.

My first thought was to prepare some special template filter that will convert every recognized word in a given variable to the text with base forms rather then forms. Then I could use it in search index templates in django+haystack. If search query will be also converted before evaluate in whoosh engine this should work great. See example:

```
haystack search index template:
    {{some_indexed_text|convert_to_base_form_filter}}

text to index: "Nie ma komputera"  => "Nie ma komputer" <- this is really indexed
 search query: "komputery"         => "komputer"   <-- this will match
```

But I don't think that this is "elegant" solution of this problem, also some other features won't work - like suggesting misspelling suggestions.

So - how  should I solve this issue? Maybe I should use other search engine than whoosh?

Comment: It should be noted that search by index without a stemmer might be approximately 10 times faster. So using wildcard like `komputer*` can be preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoosh has, by default, only stemming for the english language.
To implement stemming for another language, first look inside:

```
/your_path_to_whoosh/whoosh/lang/analysis.py
```

This is where `StemmingAnalyzer` (the default analyzer) is defined and an excellent starting point. The `stem` function, imported from `porter.py`, is the other important place to look in.

So, the three steps are:

- Implement your own stemming function, taking as a reference the stem function in porter.py and any grammar and language references you will need to get the rules right.
- Implement your own Analyzer taking as reference `StemmingAnalyzer` inside `analysis.py`. The file is heavily documented so you should have no problem navigating through it. You'll see that `StemmingAnalyzer` is basically a chaining of a `Tokenizer` with a regex to match words, a lowercase filter and the stemming filter which basically calls the above stemming function. You'll see that `StemFilter` takes the stemming function as a parameter, so you don't have to reimplement the filter.
- Pass your brand new Analyzer function at schema creation time, see here: http://files.whoosh.ca/whoosh/docs/latest/schema.html#creating-a-schema

Answer (score 5):

For future readers: Whoosh can handle different languages with snowball stemmer.

```
from whoosh.lang.snowball.russian import RussianStemmer
stemmer_ru = RussianStemmer()
analyzer = StemmingAnalyzer(stemfn=stemmer_ru.stem)
schema = fields.Schema(
    name=fields.TEXT(analyzer=analyzer),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoosh LanguageAnalyzer:

Configures a simple analyzer for the given language, with a LowercaseFilter, StopFilter, and StemFilter.

https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/analysis.html#whoosh.analysis.LanguageAnalyzer